# Bad things with FTP server and Android WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, ftp

I have really basic question over here. I want to play videos in my Android app through my webview and I'd like to make it expandable to full screen while I can't. There is no problem with playing YouTube videos by coping embed code from video but difficulties appear when I try to play it from my FTP server. I don't know how to get embed code from video placed on it. Please help me with these issues.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       filmkey = "<iframe width=\"95%\" height=\"95%\" src=\"ftp://123.456.7.89/\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

        screen=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        screen.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String myvideokey = filmkey;
        screen.loadData(myvideokey, "text/html", "utf-8");
        screen.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        });
```

Comment: ``ftp://123.456.7.89/`` is not a file but a directory. Can you log into that ftp server without credentials? Also: why the javascript tag?

Comment: javascript tag? sorry i made a mistake:). Link I used was "ftp://192.168.0.18/Asteroid%20Field%20-%20Empire%20Strikes%20Back%20[1080p%20HD]_HD.mp4" so there was indication on the file:(